# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly with Entity Framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, poco

I have 2 POCO classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public virtual Student { get; set; }
}
```

I also set below settings for my DbContext:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I used WCF project to pull out :
myContext.Students.Include(s => s.Courses).ToList();

at Web Service client I get The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. error

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Can you turn on tracing in the service and give us the exception that closed the channel? If you're not sure how to do it I recorded a screencast here http://rocksolidknowledge.com/ScreenCasts.mvc/Watch?video=WCFTracing.wmv that shows how to enable tracing

Comment: Have you tried debugging your service. Also at times entity framework objects do not serialize properly hence can you populate them in normal POCO which is different from your entities and try returning them

Comment: @RichardBlewett error is: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetStudents(). The InnerException message was 'Object graph for type 'WCFAPI.Model.Course' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Comment: I found the issue: we do not need this line: public virtual Student { get; set; }